# To upgrade the Xcode 8.2.1, system libraries AVAsset error

Tags: ios, xcode

this is the error screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb0L4.jpg)
Before upgrading, it can be work, after upgrading appear this error

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Comment: Not find the problem，I am using xcode 8.1